# how to select values from a user defined type?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, user-defined-types

I've sorted my data into a user defined type where Dy is the date of the measurement, Tm is the time, and pH is the measurement.

```
Type pHData
    Dy As Date
    Tm As Date
    pH As Single
End Type
```

Now I would like to sort the data by day (each day has a different number of data points), so that I can find the mean, min, max, etc. I've already made an array of the unique dates, so now I want to select values for each unique date

Something like (sorry the syntax is not perfect, but I hope you get the idea):

```
For i = LBound(uniqueArr) to UBound(uniqueArr)
  For j = LBound(pHData) to UBound(pHData)
    if pHData.Dy(j)== uniqueArr(i)
       'store in temp array to find mean, etc.' 
    else
        Next i
  Next j
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your data in an Excel sheet? Is there any reason why you do not wish to use the Excel statistical worksheet functions : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/list-of-worksheet-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx?

Comment: If you have many values, then it will execute quicker if you code it than if you do it the lazy way in Excel.

Comment: Will do. I was waiting for my registered and unregistered accounts to be merged. Now, it's all sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the min, max, mean, then you don't need to store the values in a temp array. See example below. Also, take care to write `pHData(j).Dy`, not `pHData.Dy(j)`.

```
For i = LBound(uniqueArr) to UBound(uniqueArr)
  ' Re-initialise min, max, sum
  phMin = VeryLargeNumber   ' Choice of VeryLargeNumber depends on your application. 
  phMax = - VeryLargeNumber ' Make it beyond the range of possible pH values. 
  phSum = 0
  phCount = 0
  For j = LBound(pHData) to UBound(pHData)
    With phData(j)
    If .Dy== uniqueArr(i)

       ' These will be used to calculate the mean later           
       phCount = phCount + 1
       phSum = phSum + .pH  

       ' Is this the max or min so far?
       If .pH > phMax Then
         ' This is the largest pH value encountered so far
         phMax = .pH
       ElseIf .pH < phMin Then
         ' This is the smallest pH value encountered so far
         phMin = .pH
       Else
         ' This pH value is neither the largest nor smallest encountered so far.
         ' Do nothing.
       End If

    Else
       ' This measurement was not taken on this date. 
       ' Do nothing.
    End If
    End With

    phMean = phSum / phCount 

    ' Here goes some code to store this date's 
    ' min, max, and mean somewhere convenient.

  Next j
Next i
```

If you really want to store things in a temp array, the code will be more messy and also slower... Here we go:

```
Dim todaysValues() As [Whatever type you need]

For i = LBound(uniqueArr) to UBound(uniqueArr)

  ' First, count how many measurements were taken today.
  phCount = 0
  For j = LBound(pHData) to UBound(pHData)
    If phData(j).Dy== uniqueArr(i)
       phCount = phCount + 1
    Else
       ' This measurement was not taken on this date. 
       ' Do nothing.
    End If
  Next j

  ' Now resize the temp array and store today's measurements in it.
  ReDim todaysValues(1 To phCount)
  phCount = 0
  For j = LBound(pHData) to UBound(pHData)
    If phData(j).Dy== uniqueArr(i)
       phCount = phCount + 1
       todaysValues(phCount) = phData(j).pH
    Else
       ' This measurement was not taken on this date. 
       ' Do nothing.
    End If
  Next j

  ' Here goes some code to calculate statistics (min, max, etc.)

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to store Date and Time information separately?

They're both handled as a floating point data, where the integer part represents the date whereas the decimal part, the time.

Example: *40589.5*

40589 represents the day (today)
0.5 represents the time (midday)

Converting this value to date / time format, you'll have *15/Feb/2011 12:00 PM*

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking I could match the Date information with an array of the unique days to sort the data by day. In this case, I don't really care about the time, I just want to use the day to group the data.

Something like:

```
If phData(1).Dy == Day(1)
    Then add phData(1).pH to tempArray
    'and find the mean, max, min, etc of tempArray
```